# Error 401 when accessing Google Photos API

Tags: powershell, rest, google-oauth, google-photos-api

I am facing an error 401 when accessing Google Photos API within a Powershell script. I have created a desktop project in cloud console, enabled all Photos APIs, created OAuth credentials and consent screen. While the script will pass initial OAuth authorisation, it will fail when invoking the request to the Photos API.

Code:

```powershell
    $clientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    $clientSecret = "XXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYY";
    
    $scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata"
    # Open browser and authorise
    Start-Process "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=$clientId&scope=$([string]::Join("%20", $scopes))&access_type=offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"    
     
    # paste auth code from browser
    $code = Read-Host "Please enter the code"
       
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientid&client_secret=$clientSecret&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code"
    $token_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    $redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    $grant_type = "authorization_code";
    $body = @{
        code = $code;
        client_id = $clientId;
        client_secret = $clientSecret;
        redirect_uri = $redirect_uri;
        grant_type = $grant_type;
      };
    $token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $token_uri -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    $token.refresh_token
    # Working good, we get token correctly !!!

    # Now the faulty block
    $requestUri = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums?pagesize=20"  
    $method = "GET"
    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $($token.refresh_token)";
        ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    $body = $null

    # Throws 401
    try {
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $requestUri -Method $method
    }
    catch {
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
        $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $streamReader.Close()
    }
 $ErrResp  | ConvertTo-Json
```

This will output:

```
{
    "error":  {
                  "code":  401,
                  "message":  "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
                  "status":  "UNAUTHENTICATED"
              }
}
```

Comment: What are the response headers? 401 should give you more info there. -- Also what do you get for `$token.refresh_token.GetType().FullName` ?

Comment: `$token.refresh_token.GetType().FullName` return `System.String`.  Modified the code above to decode error: `{
    "error":  {
                  "code":  401,
                  "message":  "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
                  "status":  "UNAUTHENTICATED"
              }
}`

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work! I was using the refresh token in place of the auth token.
Also it was required to modify `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

New code:

```
$clientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    $clientSecret = "XXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYY";
    
    $scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata"
    # Open browser and authorise
    Start-Process "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=$clientId&scope=$([string]::Join("%20", $scopes))&access_type=offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"    
     
    # paste auth code from browser
    $code = Read-Host "Please enter the code"
       
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientid&client_secret=$clientSecret&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code"
    $token_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    $redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    $grant_type = "authorization_code";
    $body = @{
        code = $code;
        client_id = $clientId;
        client_secret = $clientSecret;
        redirect_uri = $redirect_uri;
        grant_type = $grant_type;
      };
    $token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $token_uri -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    $token.refresh_token
    $access_token = $token.access_token
$requestUri = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums"  
$method = "GET"
$Headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $access_token";
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    $body = $null

    # Throws 401
    try {
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $requestUri -Method $method
    }
    catch {
        $streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
        $ErrResp = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
        $streamReader.Close()
    }
```

Comment: You can store the `Refresh Token` , so when the `Access Token` expires you just generate new one by using the `Refresh Token` that you "securely" sorted.

Comment: @VasilNikolov, could you post a code sample? Do you use a timer to manage expiration, before issuing any call to the API?

Comment: I dont have code in handy right now, but its fairly straight forward. 1st you need to allow the token to be refreshed check `access_type`  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient 2nd you generate it the same way. 3rd you can either track for auth error or make a countdown as access token life is 3600 seconds I think, but you can handle that in many ways.